# Why does one kernel work, but the other doesn't, when they are identical to the byte?

Tags: files, linux-kernel, block-device

I have a couple of scripts, that build Linux live CDs for me.

I have a couple of kernels, that I built myself to use for these. Having built one such Live CD a couple of weeks back with a kernel, everything works fine and I can still build it, from the gathered build files.

When trying to build the exact same Live CD from scratch, where it gathers the same kernel, it won't boot.

I compared the kernel in the weeks old build directory and the one used now and `diff` declares them to be identical.

`cmp bzImage kernel/vmlinuz-4.15.18` returns `0`

```
> md5sum  bzImage kernel/vmlinuz-4.15.18 
7add044e080dc32e7810bf803450c95c  bzImage
7add044e080dc32e7810bf803450c95c  kernel/vmlinuz-4.15.18
```

`stat` has the following to say:

```
  File: bzImage # works
  Size: 7996976     Blocks: 15624      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 3714381     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ me)   Gid: ( 1000/ me)
Access: 2019-01-08 20:00:48.842172091 +0100
Modify: 2018-12-10 15:43:47.428001000 +0100
Change: 2018-12-10 15:43:47.428001000 +0100
 Birth: -


  File: kernel/vmlinuz-4.15.18 # doesn't work
  Size: 7996976     Blocks: 15432      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 538209      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ me)   Gid: ( 1000/ me)
Access: 2019-01-08 18:49:41.205420092 +0100
Modify: 2019-01-08 16:12:03.858957307 +0100
Change: 2019-01-08 16:12:03.858957307 +0100
 Birth: -
```

The only apparent difference is the block number, which seems to be too low for the file size of the one that doesn't work. What is happening here?

Example of what the script does with the kernel:

```
# create disk and partition
guestfish disk-create image.img raw 1000000 # kb
guestfish -- add image.img : run : part-add /dev/sda primary $BOOT_START_SECTOR $BOOT_END_SECTOR
guestfish -- add image.img : run : mkfs ext4 /dev/sda1 label:l_boot

# copy linux file hierarchy onto partition
guestfish -- add image.img : run : mount /dev/sda1 / : copy-in rootfs/* /

# mount and copy kernel from build dir onto vdi
guestfish -- add image.img : run : mount /dev/sda1 / : mount-local "mnt/" : mount-local-run
# [...]
cp iso/boot/bzImage mnt/vmlinuz # the kernel

# install extlinux on top
guestfish -- add image.img : run : mount /dev/sda1 / : extlinux /
```

I also ran `stat` and `md5sum` on the copied file on the created vdi (not the one in the build system) and the results are the same as for kernel/vmlinuz above.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88101/discussion-on-question-by-minix-why-does-one-kernel-work-but-the-other-doesnt).